# Add New SVG Icon To Font Awesome

Tags: font-awesome

I have my own custom SVG. I have font awesome working on a site I own. I'm not familiar with exactly how it is installed etc. Are there any really basic instructions on how to add an icon to it please?

Answer (score 0):

I am reading and trying these instructions here http://spin.atomicobject.com/2012/12/16/create-your-own-font-awesome-icons/